# How we can access SharePoint 2019 on-premises on mobile device Android + IPhone?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-on-prem

We tried to access SharePoint 2019 on-Premise in our android device after installed the SharePoint Apps in google play store.

We tried to login through **SharePoint server url**  option.
but not get the success.
we got the massage "**unable to connect to  SharePoint server please check the URL, or make sure your deceive is connected to your corporate network**"
Please give the advice how we access SharePoint using mobile apps.

Is we need any extra configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You on premises SharePoint site would have been on intranet which is not accessible until you are in your Organization network.

For on premises SharePoint site on Mobile app you have 2 options

1) You mobile (andriod or ios) should be connected to your organization network, It can be via wifi :)

2) You need to put your SharePoint site in extranet or internet zone(not advisable). You need to check with your infrastructure team about requirement, governance and policies.

Answer (score 1):

For the SharePoint iOS mobile app, for remote access you need to put in place a mechanism to access your farm remotely. This would mean opening up a firewall port or otherwise exposing the SharePoint farm.

Note that with on-prem, you must be using Windows Claims (NTLM) to use the SharePoint mobile app. The iOS app does support SharePoint on-prem, but I'm not sure as to the status of the Android client.

Comment: Thanks  Trevor, Can you please share some document link or articles/blog/video how we configure It.